# Python open image file and encode to base64 is empty

Tags: python, encoding, base64

I am trying to encode a file which is in a certain folder and create a base64 string. I can load the file and read() it, but creating the base64 string prints nothing.

```
for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])):
     print file
     print type(file)
     if file.startswith(str(current_user.id)):
           with open(file, 'rb') as thefile:                         
                data = thefile.read().encode("base64")
                print "base: ", data
                print "the ", type(thefile)
```

Here are the prints:

```
1-bild-1.jpg
<type 'str'>
base:  
the  <type 'file'>
```

EDIT:

I noticed that `thefile.read()` is empty aswell. print shows nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the right file? Try `open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file))`.

Comment: Yes it tells me the correct name of the file and atm. there is only one file in the directory which I can open and look at.

Comment: You're trying to open just the file "1-bild-1.jpg"… how is Python supposed to know what folder that file is in? You need to join it with the folder path.

Comment: Yeah true, it works now. Thanks

Comment: @Rawing answer the question and I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the full file path to open, not just the file's name.

Change

```
with open(file, 'rb') as thefile:
```

to

```
with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file), 'rb') as thefile:
```

and it should work.